# HTML file field with multiple files selection and add/remove files functionality

Tags: javascript, html

I need to implement a HTML form for submitting data and uploading multiple small files (number of files can vary from 1 to 30). In HTML5, there is a `multiple` attribute that allows multiple selection in one file field. I am wondering if it is possible to allow users to add/remove a single file to/from current selection. HTML5 solution is oaky, non-cross-browser solution is okay, as long as it supports Firefox.

Comment: Not sure what you ask.. you want HTML5 solution or "old" HTML/JavaScript solution?

Comment: @Shadow - HTML5 solution is oaky.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [Multiple File Upload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/) jQuery plugin, which provides that feature on non-HTML5 browsers.

Comment: I tried this plugin. It does not work for file field with `multiple` attribute. Selecting 30 files one by one is tedious for users.

Comment: @powerboy, I see, looks like I misunderstood what you wanted. I'm afraid you won't be able to do that without HTML5, then...

Answer (score 1):

Use [plupload](http://plupload.com/), it's an easy to use, library-agnostic tool for uploading files. It supports multiple-select, upload queues, pre-upload image resizing and much more.

Internally it uses a number of different runtimes depending on whats available in the browser.